# SELECT statement to count elements

Tags: sql, database

I have an SQL table consisting of:

```
[title]
ElementA
ElementA
ElementB
ElementC
ElementA
ElementA
```

I am trying to find a way to count the element which occurs the most; in this example, that would be 
`4` because `ElementA` has occurred 4 times. The problem is, this table is dynamic, so I can't just say `SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE title = 'ElementA';`

Does anyone have any idea how to compose a `SELECT` statement to do this? Conceptually, it seems pretty simple, but I just can't make it work.

Many thanks,
Brett

Comment: Homework? Always suspicious when the answer is in the first chapter of every SQL book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 Title, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY Title ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

or

```
SELECT Title, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY Title ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT = 1
```

depending on the product you're using.

(Edited to correct the ORDER BY clause).

Comment: "TOP 1" with "ORDER BY Title"? I don't think this will give you the element with the most occurences.

Comment: Oops, thanks guys. Of course, one wants to order by the count, not the title.

Comment: +1 too for doing it w/o the subquery. Which would have gone to other answers too if they didn't fail to do so :D lol

Answer (score 3):

```
Select TOP 1 Title

FROM


(

Select 
   Count(title) k, title
FROM
    titles
GROUP BY 
   TITLE

) Count

 ORDER BY
      k Desc
```

Comment: I would put the "TOP 1" into the second select, but that's just cosmetics, I guess.

Comment: @Ttoni No, he has no order by in the inner select, it could be any row

Comment: @bernd_k: I would swear it was there when I wrote the comment, but I see no edit history, so it must be my limited vision :-)

Comment: @TToni I had made a formatting mistake which separated the order by from the rest of it and fixed it. SO doesn't put in an edit history if you do it fast enough.

Comment: I don't think a nested query is necessary for this SELECT.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to get a complete list

```
SELECT Title, Count (*) as NumOccurences
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Title
Order BY NumOccurences
```

To just get the top dog, use the following with some flavor changes to suit your SQL syntax

```
SELECT TOP 1 Title, NumOccurences
FROM 
(
    SELECT Title, Count (*) NumOccurences
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY Title
    Order BY Count (*) DESC
) AS Titles
```

Comment: Give it a "TOP 1" and add a DESC to that order by and you're in business. Except that the OP only asked for the Title :-)

Comment: Actually, that gets the _least_ count, not the greatest.

Comment: You can use **ORDER BY NumOccurences**, leverage the capability of your RDBMS (Sql Server, Postgresql, MySQL can perform ORDER BY on projected data, i.e. can use aliases on ORDER BY), that makes for a readable program.  Anyway, if one is using Access, there's no other choice but to repeat the operation on **ORDER** clause :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    Title, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Title
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

Postgresql, MySQL, etc:

```
SELECT 
    Title, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Title
ORDER BY Count DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I would not recommend using the reserved word `COUNT` as the name for the column.

Comment: actually it's fine. SELECT is a projection clause, and as such is the last operation executed(i.e. after filtering, grouping), won't affect other operations, so descriptive name is encouraged. If SQL follows the LINQ clauses ordering (**from** comes first, **select** comes last), e.g. from p in records select new { Title = p.Key, Count = p.Count()) }, the descriptive name isn't odd. So to each his own :-)

Comment: Not everything that can be done should be done.  I have to go with Raj, there are plenty of non-reserved synonyms for "count".

Comment: Not because it can be done, it's because it's natural to do so. Furthermore, I'm using Postgres, that's why that rationale. If you don't put an alias on `COUNT(*)` or any functions for that matter, it is the name of the function that is projected on resultset.  It's no different than declaring the name of the variable from the name of its type, `public DataSet DataSet { get; }`. There's no ambiguity that can be deduced on that

Answer (score 0):

Use a group by to group the elements followed by a max on der respective count.. Use nested queries to make the solution simpler.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE (Title, Counter) as
 (SELECT Title, Count(*) Counter FROM #Test GROUP BY Title) 

SELECT Top 1 Title, Counter FROM CTE order by Counter Desc
```